# How to detect which error brought us on errors page

Tags: html, asp.net, custom-error-pages

I hear that we can use `defaultRedirect` clause of the `<customErrors>` section to specify a custom errors page (or more than one, each one handling a specific HTTP error). I added an error page to my project and set it like so in `web.config`. Now when an HTTP error occurs, ASP.NET takes me to the designated error page, but I'm not sure exactly what happened that took us here.

Is there a way for us to tell ASP.NET to spit out error code or description in our page? Adding one page for each HTTP error seems to be a lot of work. I'm looking for some server-side variable/macro or something I could embed in that page's body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Server.GetLastError() method.

From MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524846%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> The GetLastError method returns an ASPError Object describing the
>   error condition that occurred. This method is available only before
>   the .asp file has sent any content to the client.

This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10593/Error-Handling-in-ASP-NET) on CodeProject has a pretty good tutorial on error handling in ASP.net.